# LocalDB Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, localdb

I just installed VS 2012 Express on a fresh Windows image and plan to use the built in localdb functionality to handle SQL databases without installing SQL Server Express. I can the instance name set to (localdb)\v11.0.

When I attempt to add an SQL Database to my project I receive an error stating that SAL Server Express 2005 or greater is required to add this type of file.

Any idea why LocalDB is not working for me the way it should? I have it working on my old laptop but cant get it to work on my new. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed LocalDB and all is well.